How can I measure a 100 MHz signal with unknown source impedance with an oscilloscope?
As a part of a device I designed, I have to measure multiple higher frequency square wave (and sinusodial) signals with unkown source impedance. The intended signal path is shown in the picture:

My questions are:

How should I design the wire from the DuT to the PCB?
How should I design the PCB trace?
Should I terminate the signal at the oscilloscope input? (I do not want to use a probe between the oscilloscope and the PCB.)

The goal is to achieve low distortion of the signal to measure the frequency and amplitude correctly without loading the source too much, but I don't really know how to approach this.

You need to know the state the potential source impedance range at the very least or, find a way of using a header amp right up at the source at the DUT end of the needles.

The problem with your probe being 'test needles + wire' is that it's likely to be fairly high inductance, high that is compared to the 50 ohm impedance of the rest of your setup.
As you have 50 ohms from your PCB through to the oscilloscope, and presumably the oscilloscope set on 50 ohm input, I would recommend keeping your PCB as close to 50 ohms as you can. Keeping the traces to 50 ohms is fairly easy. You may need to choose or match your relay however. Some relays may have excessive inductance and need a bit of extra C to ground to make them into a well-matched low pass filter. Some relays may look capacitive to ground, and need a sniff of series inductance to match them.
To deal with 'not loading your DUT too much', and also to mitigate the poorly contolled excess inductance of 'needles+wire', I would recommend the 'poor man's RF probe' approach of a series 1k resistor in series with the pins and wire. This does several things.
1 - Most high frequency devices will be able to tolerate a 1k resistive loading without misbehaving, this applies to both logic and analogue RF.
2 - The 1k resistor into the 50 load of cable+'scope will give you a reasonably frequency-flat 26 dB attenuator pad.
3 - The high impedance of the extra inductance of the needles + wire is now compared to 1k rather than 50 ohms, so you should be better able to tolerate it.

Thank you very much! Should i try to keep the impedance of the "test needles + wire" consistent over the entire length?

@Robert if you can control the impedance, then great. I assumed 'wire' would be just that, and so not very controllable. If you put the 1k resistor at the test needle, then it doesn't matter too much whether your subsequent connection is 50 ohms (ideally) or a short piece of higher impedance wire. If you need precision, then you will have proper connections in coax from end to end. If you are using a bed of nails, then you have already sacrificed much precision and repeatability, and have to make the best of a bad job the with the series resistors.

Sorry for not thanking you for your comment. I was a little busy. I did a simple transmission line simulation and your suggestion seems to help. Could you explain the third point of your answer a little more? Is there an improvement in imedance mismatch with the series resistor or do i have other things to consider? Thanks a lot!

@Robert It's not a comment, it's an answer. If it helped you, you could 'accept' the answer. Let's say your wiring has 100 nH inductance, That's 60 johms impedance at 100 MHz. In a 50 ohm system, an extra 60 ohms is a big error. In a 1kohm system, it's a tiny error. The resistor doesn't improve the impedance mismatch of the wire, it reduces its effect.
